# How to replace a word in string message?

Tags: java, str-replace

I have been at this for a while try a few different codes. When I try to replace the word says my replace code is wrong .how can I've replaced all words in messages?

```
public class StorySynthesiser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String message;
        String name ="Tiger";
        String result = message.replaceAll("Hare", name);


        message = "";
        message = message +"There once was a speedy Hare who bragged about how fast he could run.\n";
        message = message +"Tired of hearing him boast, the Tortoise challenged him to a race.\n";
        message = message +"All the animals in the forest gathered to watch.\n";
        message = message +"The Hare ran down the road for a while and then paused to rest. \n";
        message = message +"He looked back at the tortoise and cried out, \"How do you expect to win this race when you are walking along at your slow, slow pace?\n";
        message = message +"The Tortoise walked and walked, never ever stopping until he came to the finish line.\n";       
        message = message +"The animals who were watching cheered so loudly for Tortoise that they woke up the Hare. The Hare stretched, yawned and began to run again, but it was too late.\n";
        message = message +"Tortoise had already crossed the finish line in 2 hours ago/n";



        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

Comment: When you try to call `replaceAll` on the `message` variable, it is not yet initialized. Try to move `String result = message.replaceAll("Hare", name)` below the message text.

Comment: Oh and replace `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message)` with `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initiallize your `message` variable during declaration,since its all synchronous you have to put `replaceAll` after you have appended in `message` variable ,otherwise you will get an empty string.

```
    public class StorySynthesiser  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String message=""; // initailize your message here
        String name ="Tiger";
        message = message +"There once was a speedy Hare who bragged about how fast he could run.\n";
        message = message +"Tired of hearing him boast, the Tortoise challenged him to a race.\n";
        message = message +"All the animals in the forest gathered to watch.\n";
        message = message +"The Hare ran down the road for a while and then paused to rest. \n";
        message = message +"He looked back at the tortoise and cried out, \"How do you expect to win this race when you are walking along at your slow, slow pace?\n";
        message = message +"The Tortoise walked and walked, never ever stopping until he came to the finish line.\n";       
        message = message +"The animals who were watching cheered so loudly for Tortoise that they woke up the Hare. The Hare stretched, yawned and began to run again, but it was too late.\n";
        message = message +"Tortoise had already crossed the finish line in 2 hours ago/n";
String result = message.replaceAll("Hare", name);
    System.out.println(result);

    }}
```

Working [repl](https://repl.it/repls/CompassionateFirmBrace)

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing first and assigning values later, and also displaying the other variable in your `DialogPane`, so you need to do this as:

```
    String name ="Tiger";


    message = "";
    message = message +"There once was a speedy Hare who bragged about how fast he could run.\n";
    message = message +"Tired of hearing him boast, the Tortoise challenged him to a race.\n";
    message = message +"All the animals in the forest gathered to watch.\n";
    message = message +"The Hare ran down the road for a while and then paused to rest. \n";
    message = message +"He looked back at the tortoise and cried out, \"How do you expect to win this race when you are walking along at your slow, slow pace?\n";
    message = message +"The Tortoise walked and walked, never ever stopping until he came to the finish line.\n";       
    message = message +"The animals who were watching cheered so loudly for Tortoise that they woke up the Hare. The Hare stretched, yawned and began to run again, but it was too late.\n";
    message = message +"Tortoise had already crossed the finish line in 2 hours ago/n";

   String result = message.replaceAll("Hare", name);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code, when you call to replaceAll, message is null.
You have to call it after asignation.

```
 String message = "";
String name ="Tiger";


message += "There once was a speedy Hare who bragged about how fast he could run.\n";
message += "Tired of hearing him boast, the Tortoise challenged him to a race.\n";
message += "All the animals in the forest gathered to watch.\n";
message += "The Hare ran down the road for a while and then paused to rest. \n";
message += "He looked back at the tortoise and cried out, \"How do you expect to win this race when you are walking along at your slow, slow pace?\n";
message += "The Tortoise walked and walked, never ever stopping until he came to the finish line.\n";       
message += "The animals who were watching cheered so loudly for Tortoise that they woke up the Hare. The Hare stretched, yawned and began to run again, but it was too late.\n";
message += "Tortoise had already crossed the finish line in 2 hours ago/n";


String result = message.replaceAll("Hare", name);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the replacement *after* you have actually assigned content to the message:

```
String message = "content here...";
String result = message.replaceAll("Hare", name);
```

Note that since you are not actually doing a regex replacement, you might as well just use `String#replace` here for better performance:

```
String result = message.replace("Hare", name);
```

Comment: No idea why the downvote; +1 from me just for being the only one to mention `replace` vs `replaceAll` (although I'd change "you might as well" to "you most definitely should", not for performance but for not being surprised when doing the same with regex special characters)

Comment: @tobias_k The downvote is a punishment for answering such a trivial question, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to change here

Initialize variable

```
   String message;
```

and call replace at end as below.

```
    String message = "";
    String name ="Tiger";


    message = message +"There once was a speedy Hare who bragged about how fast he could run.\n";
    message = message +"Tired of hearing him boast, the Tortoise challenged him to a race.\n";
    message = message +"All the animals in the forest gathered to watch.\n";
    message = message +"The Hare ran down the road for a while and then paused to rest. \n";
    message = message +"He looked back at the tortoise and cried out, \"How do you expect to win this race when you are walking along at your slow, slow pace?\n";
    message = message +"The Tortoise walked and walked, never ever stopping until he came to the finish line.\n";       
    message = message +"The animals who were watching cheered so loudly for Tortoise that they woke up the Hare. The Hare stretched, yawned and began to run again, but it was too late.\n";
    message = message +"Tortoise had already crossed the finish line in 2 hours ago/n";

    String result = message.replaceAll("Hare", name);


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

Comment: Why do you think it is necessary to initialize the variable when it is declared?

Comment: @tobias_k Because in the first line (after name variable)he is trying to append variable itself with message and without initialization compiler won't allow it. Its not necessary to initialize during declaration you can also initialize it later as it been done in question, Both meant to same. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the string **before** setting the message. Consider changeing the order:

```
        String message; //message is now null, trying to replace will cause a Null pointer exception.
        String name ="Tiger";


        message = ""; //message is now an empty string, replaceing something will be useless as there is nothing there.
        message = message +"There once was a speedy Hare who bragged about how fast he could run.\n";
        message = message +"Tired of hearing him boast, the Tortoise challenged him to a race.\n";
        message = message +"All the animals in the forest gathered to watch.\n";
        message = message +"The Hare ran down the road for a while and then paused to rest. \n";
        message = message +"He looked back at the tortoise and cried out, \"How do you expect to win this race when you are walking along at your slow, slow pace?\n";
        message = message +"The Tortoise walked and walked, never ever stopping until he came to the finish line.\n";       
        message = message +"The animals who were watching cheered so loudly for Tortoise that they woke up the Hare. The Hare stretched, yawned and began to run again, but it was too late.\n";
        message = message +"Tortoise had already crossed the finish line in 2 hours ago/n";


        //here message is full and has some "Hare" to replace.
        String result = message.replaceAll("Hare", name);


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

Check this off-topic tip:

```
message = message + "hello";
```

is the same as:

```
message += "hello";
```